# Entity framework for tables where there are 2 columns to create a relationship to

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have a database where I have a table with primary key in the form of a string.

Example:

```
"{5EFCA789-02F6-4CFE-9B1C-0EADF2907169}"
```

And also the same key in another column in the form of a GUID

```
5EFCA789-02F6-4CFE-9B1C-0EADF2907169
```

The issue is that in the current code all tables that relate to it use the string key, but I have to add a relation to the table that only has the GUID foreign key.

Is it possible to create a relation in entity framework like that with the Fluent API?

In EF7 there is a way to specify an alternate key and that seems to be what I need, but is there a way to make this work in EF6?

If needed, I can explain the issue further.

EDIT: I have a very complex database with tons of tables. But I'll make an example with relevant info.

Table 1: Organizations has columns

```
Org_id | org_guid | org_name
```

Table 2: Units has columns(this is the one that is related to the table via Org_id that is a string)

```
Unit_id | org_id | unit_name
```

Table 3: Organization benefits(this is the one I need to create a relation with)

```
benefit_id | org_guid | benefit_name
```

NB. I am not allowed to change the table design.

The organization table has to have a one-to-many relation with both other tables.
What I need to show for example is a table of benefits with benefit_name and organization_name.

Comment: Can you give a brief overview of your tables? And what data you'd like to present given the 'id'

Comment: Also, any code you've written would be helpful

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: I could post the code of the entities and entity type configurations, but I don't feel they are relevant as I have no idea how to approach the issue.